ngFor item div toggle class on click
I have a ngFor where it gets the static data from the .ts file, I'm trying to add active class on the selected item, the issue is as it is in ngfor it toggles class on every item on the list. How can I add active class to the selected item?
    <div
        class="mb-2 item rounded bg-white border"
        *ngFor="let item of keys(); let i = index"
        (click)="ItemSelectClick(item)"
        [ngClass]="ItemSelectStatus ? 'active' : ''">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="cursor-pointer">
          <figure>
            <div class="p-5">
              <img
                src="{{ item[1].image }}"
                class="rounded-t mx-auto mb-4"
                width="75"
              />
              <figcaption>
                <p class="text-lg mb-3 font-semibold leading-relaxed">
                  {{ item[1].name }}
                </p>

                <div class="flex justify-between">
                  <span class="leading-5 font-semibold">
                    {{ item[1].calories }} Cal.
                  </span>
                  <span class="leading-5 font-semibold">
                    ${{ item[1].price }}
                  </span>
                </div>
              </figcaption>
            </div>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>

import { Component, inject, OnInit, ViewChild } from "@angular/core";
import { CartItemService } from "src/app/shared/services/cart-item.service";
import { ToastService } from "src/app/shared/services/helpers/toaster.service";

@Component({
  selector: "wrap-menu",
  templateUrl: "./wrap-menu.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./wrap-menu.component.scss"],
})
export class wrapComponent implements OnInit {
  toastService = inject(ToastService);

  isSelected = false;
  selectedItem: any;
  showToaster: boolean = false;
  toasterMessage: string = "";

  chickenMenuItem = [
    {
      id : 1,
      name: "Shawarma",
      image: "../../../assets/images/kebab.png",
      calories: "34",
      price: "23",
    },
    {
      id : 2,
      name: "American Roll",
      image: "../../../assets/images/wrap2.png",
      calories: "23",
      price: "24",
    },
    {
      id : 3,
      name: "Mexican Kebab",
      image: "../../../assets/images/item.png",
      calories: "34",
      price: "75",
    },
    {
      id : 5,
      name: "Kebab",
      image: "../../../assets/images/wrap1.png",
      calories: "53",
      price: "35",
    },
    {
      id : 6,
      name: "Spicy Fries",
      image: "../../../assets/images/kebab.png",
      calories: "22",
      price: "23",
    },
    {
      id : 7,
      name: "Turkish Kebab",
      image: "../../../assets/images/item.png",
      calories: "35",
      price: "45",
    },
    {
      id : 8,
      name: "Chicken Noodels",
      image: "../../../assets/images/item.png",
      calories: "23",
      price: "45",
    },
    {
      id : 9,
      name: "Crispy Wings",
      image: "../../../assets/images/kebab.png",
      calories: "34",
      price: "98",
    },
  ];

  constructor(private cartItemServices: CartItemService) {}

  ItemSelectStatus: boolean = false;

  ItemSelectClick(item: any) {
    this.isSelected = true;
    this.ItemSelectStatus = !this.ItemSelectStatus;
    this.selectedItem = item;
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  addItem() {
    this.cartItemServices.addItem(this.selectedItem);
    this.showToast("Item Added Successfully");
  }

  showToast(message: string): void {
    this.toasterMessage = message;
    this.showToaster = true;
    setTimeout(() => this.hideToaster(), 3000);
  }

  hideToaster(): void {
    this.showToaster = false;
    this.toasterMessage = "";
  }

  keys(): Array<any> {
    console.log(Object.entries(this.chickenMenuItem));
    return Object.entries(this.chickenMenuItem);
  }

  onCancel() {
    this.isSelected = false;
  }

  selectedIndex: number = null;



}



Add an isActive prop to the object to save and change the clicked items status:
    {
      id : 1,
      name: "Shawarma",
      image: "../../../assets/images/kebab.png",
      calories: "34",
      price: "23",
      isActive: false,
    }

And then modify the temlpate to use that value:
[ngClass]="item[1].isActive ? 'active' : ''">

Update:
This are really the basics of angular. Check the docs for more info.
Here is an working similar example:
https://angular-elements-fiddle-tnuacv.stackblitz.io
<div *ngFor="let item of chickenMenuItem">
  <div
    [ngClass]="item.isActive ? 'active' : ''"
    (click)="ItemSelectClick(item)"
  >
    {{ item.name }}
    {{ item.isActive }}
  </div>
</div>

.active {
  color: red;
}

import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  chickenMenuItem = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Shawarma',
      image: '../../../assets/images/kebab.png',
      calories: '34',
      price: '23',
      isActive: false,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'American Roll',
      image: '../../../assets/images/wrap2.png',
      calories: '23',
      price: '24',
      isActive: false,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Mexican Kebab',
      image: '../../../assets/images/item.png',
      calories: '34',
      price: '75',
      isActive: false,
    },
  ];

  constructor() {}

  ItemSelectClick(item: any) {
    item.isActive = !item.isActive;
  }
}


tried this, it doesn't add class

You have an issue with the current list, You add [1] to the item object, so You get an array. If that's what You want update to item[1].isActive .

Yes, this is an array. I tried making the change to item object it doesnt add class after the above changes
